# How to access protected variable of class inside static method of the same class?

Tags: php, class, methods, static

Below is the scenario:

```
class PopupsAdminSettingsPage extends AbstractAdminSubPage
{
    protected $menuTitle = 'Settings';

    public static function getMenuTitle()
    {
        /* I want to access $menuTitle property here ...
    }
}
```

I want to access the `$menuTitle` property inside the static function `getMenuTitle` so that I could access the protected variable outside of the `Class PopupsAdminSettingsPage` too.

Comment: This is not something you should be doing but yes it's possible

Comment: This doesn't sound like good practice

Comment: You should in general, avoid use of static methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public static function getMenuTitle(&$PopupsAdminSettingsPage)
{
  echo $PopupsAdminSettingsPage->menuTitle
}
```

But that doesn't mean it's right to do this. You can't access it for a reason

> In Static methods context there's no **$this**

So that should be a big red sign in your implementation

Comment: You should have learned some basics since release of 5.0 (I think, it was in 2004). You are not supposed to pass objects by reference.

Comment: We're not supost to access non-static properties in static methods and we're doing it anyway as a proof of concept. I explained OP how wrong this implementation is, but it's a valid way to work around it. So why 're you downvoting a "proof of concept" answer ?

Comment: What you are doing, is perpetuating a deprecated code. This is no way affected by code being run in static context. So, please make sure, that the code you write does march the **PoC** acronyms positive version.

Comment: @tereško So if I take down the `&` it will still display the same behaviour, as per described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)

Comment: No, it will not. Passing references cause an internal ref-count to increase. When used on object handler, this will end up causing a memory leak due to it refcount never reaching again and garbage collector not being applied to occur. As for why that feature still exists, if it is harmful: well, for purposes of backwards compatibility, because this was the way for passing around objects in PHP4.